# Securing resources served from META-INF/resources with authentication in quarkus

Tags: java, authentication, jax-rs, quarkus

**What is the idiomatic way to secure static resources with authentication in quarkus?**

In [quarkus.io](https://quarkus.io) it's very easy to secure JAX-RS resources, e.g. via [jwt](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt) or [BasicAuth](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-built-in-authentication#basic-auth). But I failed to identify how to secure the resources served from `resources/META-INF/resources` with the same authentication mechanism.

As a workaround, we read the files placed directly into `resources` and wrote an passthrough JAX-RS resource:

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("static")
public class StaticResources {

    @Inject
    protected JsonWebToken jwt; 

    @GET
    @Path("{filename}")
    public Response serve(@PathParam("filename") String file) {
        if (! hasValidJwt()) {
            return Response.status(401).build();
        }
        return Response.ok(loadFromFile(file)).build();
    }

    ...
}
```

This works fine (for our purposes)! But I assume that there are better ways to solve this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I'm not wrong you can define paths in `application.properties` and protect them.

Here is an example:

https://quarkus.io/guides/security-authorization

the relevant lines are:

```
quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.paths=/*
quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.policy=authenticated
```